# Can gas turbine engines be used for railways

Tags: jet-engine

Is it possible that gas turbine engines can be used for railways  , even though it may posses some risk such as Foreign object damage , can it be efficient such as electric trains but it can act as stand alone system

Comment: Not sure if AviationSE is the right place for this question.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Gas Turbine Locomotive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_turbine_locomotive)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using the exhaust thrust to push the train, I am not sure. If you mean using the power from the shaft of the turbine to derive mechanical work, it's been done: [JetTrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetTrain) .

Note that the gas turbine was only efficient for high speeds, and there were more traditional drive trains (diesel electric) for lower speed operations and idling.

Comment: The [turbojet train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbojet_train) has been tried.

Comment: Also consider that many trains are electric, and gas turbine generators are used to generate electricity, so in a sense they're turbine trains.  With all the advantages of leaving most of your engine and its problems elsewhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

This has been done multiple times, see [Turbojet train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbojet_train). Only few really jet-powered trains have been built, for research in high-speed rail. [Gas turbine locomotive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_turbine_locomotive) is a less extreme attempt to use a turbine for powering the wheels (rather than moving the train with its direct thrust).